# Going back to previous JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, windowbuilder

I am trying to navigate back to a JPanel and was unsure of how to do this. Whenever I try to use the following

```
public class RemoveDE extends JPanel {

private JPanel DEadminhome;

public removeDE(){

setVisible(false);

parent.setContentPane(DEadminhome);

setLayout(null);

}                   
}
```

I get error: **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself**"

The snippet above is indicating removeDE is the current JPanel I am on and DEadminhome is the JPanel that I am attempting to navigate back to.

What would be the correct way of going about this? Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: unrelated: a) please learn Java naming conventions and stick to them. b) never-ever go without a LayoutManager

Comment: maybe parent == deAdminHome? Hard to tell without a SSCCE (hint, hint :-)

Comment: Sorry, I do deserve a hand slap for the naming convention but I can be terrible with names. However, it was requested of me that I use an absolute layout so I just set resizable equal to false. As for the SSCCE is there a way to attach it on here?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to navigate back to a JPanel and was unsure of how to do this

Try using a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). It will help you manage which panel is visible from a group of panels.